# Batch character escape on ^| don't work

Tags: windows, batch-file

^| Should be escape for the | character.

```
set good=Debug^|Win32

echo Incorrect paramets %good%

pause > nul
```

Why this give me error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two ways to insert special characters in a variable. Escaping them:

```
set good=Debug^|Win32
```

or enclosing them between quotes:

```
set "good=Debug|Win32"
```

However, *the only way* to correctly show a variable value that contain special characters is using delayed expansion:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set good=Debug^|Win32
echo Incorrect paramets !good!
pause > nul
```

Comment: That works but i can't do anything with same one in IF... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801927/escape-character-in-if

Answer (score 3):

I try to add some explanations to the main problem.

As James L. noted, you have the expected content in your variable, but it's problematic to echo it.

```
echo Incorrect parameters %good:|=^|%
```

It's a problem of the parser.
After a percent expansion special characters will be parsed, if they aren't escaped by a caret or quote.

The way of James L. only works if there are only pipes, but no other special characters in the variable, as you can't replace two different characters this way.

But you could escape all special characters twice, like:

```
set good=Debug^^^|Win32^^^&Ampersand
echo Incorrect parameters %good%
```

or the same

```
set "good=Debug^|Win32^&Ampersand"
echo Incorrect parameters %good%
```

This works, but the content of good is `Debug^|Win32^&Ampersand` which is in the most cases not wanted.

The way of Aacini, to use delayed expansion works always with any content, as after the delayed expansion the content will not further be parsed, so the special characters are harmless.
This is one of the major advantages of the delayed expansion about percent expansion.

There is another way to use quotes like the solution of Axel Kemper.

```
echo "Incorrect parameters %good%"
```

But in the most cases the quotes shouldn't be printed.

Comment: +1 I don't understand why `%good:|=^|%` works. I made several tests and this method works only as written, but fail if the caret is changed in any way: `^|=|` or `^|=^|`, or with `<` or `>`. Why `|` is treated different in this case? Thanks...

Comment: It's working as the percent replace phase is before the special character phase. So `%good:|=^|%` becomes `Debug^|Win32` just before the special characters and the carets become any effect

Comment: That works. Thank you. But i can't do anything with same one in IF... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801927/escape-character-in-if

Answer (score 1):

Try using a label.

In batch, labels are preceded by the colon.

```
:ok
```

is a label.

It is not necessary to usu the colon in a `goto`

```
goto ok
goto :ok
```

are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You properly escaped the `|` character by `set good=Debut^|Win32`.  When you `echo` it, you have to replace the `|` character with the escape sequence, like this:

```
@echo off
set good=Debug^|Win32

echo Incorrect paramets %good:|=^|%

pause > nul
```

This makes it `echo` the escaped pipe (`^\`) instead of piping it to `Win32`.

Answer (score 1):

#### use `set/p` for output:

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "good=Debug|Win32"
<nul set/p"=Incorrect parameters %good%"
echo(
```

output is:

```
Incorrect parameters Debug|Win32
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works as intended:

```
set good=Debug^|Win32

echo "Incorrect parameters %good%"

pause > nul
```

If you omit the quotes in the echo statement, Windows tries to execute "Win32" which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
echo Incorrect paramets Debug^|Win32
pause > nul
```