# escape character in IF

Tags: windows, batch-file

i tried  this in different variations (like setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion)- but nothing works:

```
echo off
IF "%1"=="Debug^|Win32"  set servicesConfig=Win2008.Debug
echo Incorrect parametr %servicesConfig%
pause > nul
```

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: myscript.bat "Debug|Win32" should return: echo Incorrect parametr Win2008.Debug

Comment: @Brans Ds - But with that input you get the line `IF ""Debug|Win32""=="Debug^|Win32" set ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quotes escapes special characters you compare the content of `%1` with `Debug^|Win32` (including the caret).

In your case you should use this

```
@echo off
IF "%~1"=="Debug|Win32" (
  echo It's ok
  set servicesConfig=Win2008.Debug
) ELSE (
  echo Unknown in "%~1"
)
```

You can call it with

```
test.bat "Debug|Win32"
or
test.bat Debug^|Win32
```

The `"%~1"` will enclose the first parameter in quotes, so special charaters are harmless, but if the first parameter is already quoted the `%~` will strip them before adding the new quotes, so you always get only one enclosing.

Answer (score 1):

if you make the following call: `script.bat "Debug|Win32"` this works:

```
@echo off&setlocal
IF "%~1"=="Debug|Win32" set "servicesConfig=Win2008.Debug"
echo Incorrect parametr %servicesConfig%
```

output is:

```
Incorrect parametr Win2008.Debug
```